# upload image and save in uploads folder

Tags: yii

Hi i am trying to upload image or file using yii but its not working. I dont have any experience in yii.can you please help me.
Here is my code Thanks in advance

This is controller SiteController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model=new ContactForm;
        if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {

            $model->attributes=$_POST['save'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '\uploads';
            //if($model->save())
           // {
                $model->image->saveAs($path);
                // redirect to success page
           // }
        }
        $this->render('index', array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

Here is my view file

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>

<h1>Welcome to <i><?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::app()->name); ?></i></h1><div class="form">
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'document-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        'action' => array( 'site/create' )
            ));
    ?>
    <?php
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
        $('.search-button').click(function(){
                $('.doc-form').toggle();
                return false;
        });
        $('.doc-form form').submit(function(){
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('document-grid', {
                        data: $(this).serialize()
                });
                return false;
        });
        ");
    ?>
    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
        <?php //echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model, 'doc_name'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->textField($model, 'doc_name', array('size' => 50, 'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
        <input type="text" name="doc_name">
        <?php //echo $form->error($model, 'doc_name'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model, 'doc_file'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->fileField($model, 'doc_file', array('size' => 36, 'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
        <input type="file" name="doc_file//">
        <?php //echo $form->error($model, 'doc_file'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php //echo $form->labelEx($model, 'summary'); ?>
        <?php //echo $form->textArea($model, 'summary', array('rows' => 6, 'cols' => 50)); ?>
        <input type="text" name="summary">
        <?php //echo $form->error($model, 'summary'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php //echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="save">
    </div>


</div>
 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

And here is my model

```
class ContactForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;
    public $verifyCode;
    public $image;

    /**
     * Declares the validation rules.
     */
    /*public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            // name, email, subject and body are required
            array('name, email, subject, body', 'required'),
            // email has to be a valid email address
            array('email', 'email'),
            // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
        );
    }
*/

    // ... other attributes

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'safe' => false),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Declares customized attribute labels.
     * If not declared here, an attribute would have a label that is
     * the same as its name with the first letter in upper case.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'verifyCode'=>'Verification Code',
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php view file like:-

```
<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Contact Us';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Contact',
);
?>
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'contact-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'body'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'body',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'body'); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'imagePath');?>
        </div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Your ContactForm Model Must Extend CActiveRecord As

```
<?php

class ContactForm extends CActiveRecord {

    public $imagePath;

    public function tableName() {
        return 'contact_form';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('name, email, subject, body', 'required'),
            array('imagePath', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'safe' => false),
            array('id, name, email, subject, body, image, created_on', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations() {
        return array(
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'subject' => 'Subject',
            'body' => 'Body',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'created_on' => 'Created On',
        );
    }

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

}
```

And Your Controller Action Must Be

```
public function actionCreate() {

        $model = new ContactForm;

        if (isset($_POST['ContactForm'])) {

            $model->attributes = $_POST['ContactForm'];
            $model->imagePath = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imagePath');

            $model->image=  Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/images/logoPhotos/'.$model->imagePath->name;

            if($model->save()){

                $path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/logoPhotos/'.$model->imagePath->name;
                $model->imagePath->saveAs($path);
                $this->redirect($this->createUrl('login'));

            }  

        }

        $this->render('index', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

You have to create a table in your database with following schema

`CREATE TABLE`contact_form`(`
id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
name`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
email`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
subject`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
body`text NOT NULL,`
image`varchar(255) NOT NULL,`
created_on`timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)`

Comment: Now i am getting this error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function saveAs() on null in D:\PHP\htdocs\manual\protected\controllers\SiteController.php on line 120

Comment: Change Your View File . as I Provided

Comment: Hey Thanks its working now can you please let me know how i can now insert it in database.

Comment: its working thanks for your help , can you please let me know how i can now insert it in database